# In every curve $\alpha$ parametrized by arc length, $\alpha''(s) \cdot \alpha'(s) = 0$

Tags: proof-explanation, curves, parametrization

In my book, in the first step of the proof they say the following, where $\cdot$ means dot product:

> Since $\alpha$ is parametrized by arc length, we have
>   $$1 = |\alpha'(t)|^2 = (\alpha'(s) \cdot\alpha'(s))$$
>   for all t

This is not at all clear to me. I don't see why that statement is true and have no idea how to prove it, and am confused that there are two different variables...

Comment: The two different variables are just a typo. It should read $1 = | \alpha'(t) |^2 = \alpha'(t) \cdot \alpha'(t)$ or, in alternative but maybe more clear notation, $1 = \| \alpha'(t) \|^2 = \left< \alpha'(t), \alpha'(t) \right>$. The expression $\alpha'(t)$ is a vector and the equation just says that the length of the vector (or, in this case, equivalently, the square of the length of the vector) is one. Does this clear the confusion or you have a different definition of what it means to be parametrized by arc length and don't understand why it is equivalent to the one you wrote?

Comment: @levap In my book all it says is that if $s(t)$ is the arc length function, then substitute the ocurrences of $t$ by $s^{-1}(t)$ to get it's parametrization by arc length. From this "definition" it is still not very clear to me why it would be true.

Comment: What is the derivative of the equation you ask about?

Comment: Use `\cdot` instead of `\bullet` for the dot product.

Answer (score 4):

I'll address the question expressed in the comment. If

$$ s(t) = \int_{a}^t | \alpha'(u) | \, du $$

is the arclength of the curve $\alpha$ (from $\alpha(a)$ to $\alpha(t)$) then by the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule, we have

$$ \frac{ds}{dt} = |\alpha'(t)|, \frac{dt}{ds} = \frac{1}{\frac{ds}{dt}} =  \frac{1}{|\alpha'(t(s))|}. $$

If we consider the curve $\alpha(t(s))$ which is parametrized by arclength and take the derivative using the chain rule, we get

$$ \frac{d}{ds}(\alpha(t(s))) = \alpha'(t(s)) \frac{dt}{ds} = \frac{\alpha'(t(s))}{|\alpha'(t(s))|} $$

which has unit length so the derivative of $\alpha$ with respect to $s$ has unit length.

Answer (score 1):

I think the $t$ in your statement should be $s$. As written it's confusing.

In any parameterization the vector $\alpha '(t)$ is the tangent vector to the curve at point $\alpha(t)$. In a short time interval the position changes by $\alpha '(t) dt$; you integrate $|\alpha '(t)| dt$ with respect to $t$ to compute the arclength up to $t$.

If $t$ is the parameterization by arclength then the arclength up to $t$ is just $t$ so the integrand $|\alpha '(t)|  $ must be identically $1$.

The last step is just the general fact that for any vector $v$
$$
|v|^2 = v \cdot v .
$$